# Combo box com cores

Tags: html, css

Queria fazer um género de um semáforo, 
Eu tenho uma combo box com 3 opções: gostava que cada uma delas tivesse uma bolinha à frente com uma cor (Verde, Laranja/Amarelo, Vermelho), para que seja mais fácil a identificação. Não esquecer que a bolinha só aparece se tiver algum item seleccionado e que cada bola corresponde a um item.

```
<tr>
  <td>Estado:</td >
  <td> 
    <select name="estado"> 
      <?php while($registo=mysql_fetch_array($consultaEstado)) { ?> 
      <option SelectedIndex = "5" value="<?php echo utf8_encode($registo['id_estado']); ?>">
        <?php echo utf8_encode($registo['tipo_estado']); ?>
      </option> 
      <?php } ?> 
    </select> 
  </td> 
  <td></td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: Eu já tenho a combobox feita, só queria mesmo essa parte da cores

Comment: Então mostre o que você tem feito.

Comment: Utilize CSS e pode tentar `<input style="background-color: red;" .....>` e um cor verde é lime, vermelho é red, laranja é orange e amarelo é yellow.

Answer (score 1):

Marcos, a tag `<select>` e `<option>` permitem poucas alternações, seja através do markup `html` ou utilizando `CSS`, e quando permite, tem muita coisa que não é `cross-browser`.

Se realmente precisa customizar o seu `select`, você terá de ocultar o mesmo e através do `javaScript` criar umà estrutura que simule o mesmo.

vamos usar como padrão o plugin `Selectize.js`, ao declarar o seguinte markup.:

```
<select id="select-beast" placeholder="Select a person...">  
  <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="1">Chuck Testa</option>
  <option value="3">Nikola Tesla</option>
  <option value="4">Sage Cattabriga-Alosa</option>
</select>
```

e fazer a seguinte chamada no javaScript:

```
$('#select-beast').selectize({
    create: true,
    sortField: 'text'
});
```

ele vai gerar o seguinte markut no seu HTML.:

```
<select id="select-beast" placeholder="Select a person..." style="display: none;">  
  <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="1">Chuck Testa</option>
  <option value="3">Nikola Tesla</option>
  <option value="4">Sage Cattabriga-Alosa</option>
</select>
<div class="selectize-control demo-default single">
  <div class="selectize-input items not-full has-options">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="" placeholder="Select a person..." style="width: 103px; opacity: 1; position: relative; left: 0px;">
  </div>
  <div class="selectize-dropdown single demo-default" style="display: none; width: 520px; top: 36px; left: 0px; visibility: visible;">
    <div class="selectize-dropdown-content">
      <div data-value="1" data-selectable="" class="option">Chuck Testa</div>
      <div data-value="3" data-selectable="" class="option">Nikola Tesla</div>
      <div data-value="4" data-selectable="" class="option">Sage Cattabriga-Alosa</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

note que neste caso, o seu `<option>` foi traduzido para uma `<div>` e você pode editar a `div` com certa liberdade.